# Angular : Customize Switch through "Y" or "N" instead of true or false

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I have an API that is giving the value of Switch in the form of "Y" or "N". I want to customize my switch in such a way that it will  "on" and "off" the value of switch through the default value coming through an API instead of true or false.

In ts file :

```
this.param.parameters.forEach( (element) => {
       
this.registerForm.addControl(element.paramId, new FormGroup({
           'FieldValue' : new FormControl(element.defaultValue),
        }))
      
    });
```

The default value assigned to the given field is "Y" or "N". I want to customize my switch on the basis of that If the value is "Y" then ON the switch otherwise "OFF" the switch.

Below is the HTML code of the switch :

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-lg">
     <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{i}}" formControlName="FieldValue">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{i}}"></label>
</div>
```

Any suggestions regarding this will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use `checked` attribute like this way `[checked]=?  FieldValue === 'Y' ? true : false;`. Remember here FieldValue is the value of your form control. Which you need to access via `this.registerForm.controls.FieldValue`

Comment: Thank you for response but getting some syntax error. Can you please elaborate your answer in answers section. It would be more helpful.

Comment: `[checked]= this.registerForm.controls.FieldValue === 'Y' ? true : false;` There was a small mistake in my comment. Just one typo. Can you please check it with current condition? I can elaborate my answer if it works